# Conversion of Mass mixing ratio (MMR) to Volume mixing ratio (VMR) and Dobson Unit?

Tags: computational-physics, atmospheric-science, unit-conversion

I am trying to convert MMR to VMR and then convert VMR to Dobson Unit (DU). I used three different methods but I get bizarre values.

[image: 1]

I used the following method to convert to Dobson [Conversion Formula Here](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=153391710). I know I results are something wrong. [Excel file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lo3qoxx3JvxQk8mvYAz9D-uHE45iQpbB/view?usp=sharing)

[image: 4]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably simpler to stick with ozone VMR, which I call $r_O$. Then if the local molecular number density is $\nu$ then the ozone number density is $r_O\nu$. To get the DU you need to integrate this over height to get the total column (moecules per unit area)
$$
\hbox{column}=\int r_O\nu\,dz.$$The local density is $\rho=\bar M \nu/N_A$ where $\bar M$ is the molecular weight of dry air, and $N_A$ is Avogadro's number.
Hydrostatic equilibrium gives us $\rho\,dz=dp/g$ so, neglecting variation of $g$ with height, we get
$$\hbox{column}=\frac{N_A}{g\bar M}\int r_O\, dp$$
which you can approximate with your data. The Dobson Unit is that column molecular abundance as a multiple of $2.69\times10^{20}$ molecules$/m^2$
(see [this page](https://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Dobson_unit)). The multiplier here is $Ph/kT$ where $P$ and $T$ are standard temperature and pressure, $k$ is Boltzmann's constant and $h$ is 10 $\mu$m.

Comment: can I get a reference to the equation plz?

Comment: I've re-worked the derivation to match the page I referenced from the American Met Soc.